# fastest way to add "N"s and concatenate millions of sequences in a fasta

Tags: python, macos, biopython

I want to concatenate all sequences in a fasta file  with a fixed number of "N"s inserted between the sequences. I tried to do this by adding a bunch of "N"s to all sequences in a fasta file and then concatenating the changed sequences using biopython (based on the cookbook [here](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec22) ). However my code prints out each of the records as they are changed and then finally the concatenated version, when I only want it to print out the latter. I would really appreciate if anyone can point out the errors in my code or suggest a better way of doing this. Thanks!

update: I corrected the code as Celeo suggested but it takes very long time to process my actual file which has >12 millions of sequences.Is there a faster an efficient way to do this using other languages (perl/awk)?
Here is a sample input

```
$ cat test.fa
>read_1
GAAGTACGT
>read_2
AACTCAAGAACAAGAAAAAA
>read_3
TGGACGACCATTCATGGCGACGTCAAGGTCAATCAT
```

Here is my code:

```
$cat merge_seq.py
import sys
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
in_file = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
sequences = SeqIO.parse(in_file, "fasta")
concat=Seq("")
for record in sequences:
    record.seq= record.seq + ("N" * 20)
    concat+=record.seq
    print concat
```

And this is the current output:

```
$ python merge_seq.py test.fa 
GAAGTACGTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
GAAGTACGTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAACTCAAGAACAAGAAAAAANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
GAAGTACGTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAACTCAAGAACAAGAAAAAANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTGGACGACCATTCATGGCGACGTCAAGGTCAATCATNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
in_file = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
sequences = SeqIO.parse(in_file, "fasta")
concat=Seq("")
for record in sequences:
    record.seq= record.seq + ("N" * 20)
    concat+=record.seq
print concat
```

Print the `concat` variable outside of the for loop after all appending is complete.

Output:

```
$ python merge_seq.py test.fa
GAAGTACGTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAACTCAAGAACAAGAAAAAANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTGGACGACCATTCATGGCGACGTCAAGGTCAATCATNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Comment: This works-- such an obvious mistake :( however this code is not very fast for my actual data (~12 million sequences), do you have any suggestions to make the processing faster? Thanks!

Comment: You could combine `record.seq= record.seq + ("N" * 20)` and `concat+=record.seq` to `concat += record.seq + ("N" * 20)` I don't know that it'll save you much, but might as well not do the extra step.

Answer (score 0):

Your code takes **minutes** with a FASTA file with 1 million entries in my PC.

The first you can try is to append each sequence to a list, and then join the list with "NNNNNNNN" (takes **13 seconds**):

```
sequences = SeqIO.parse("1Million.fas", "fasta")
seqs = []

for sequence in sequences:
    seqs.append(sequence.seq)

"NNNNNNNNNN".join(seqs)
```

Or you can get rid of the Biopython if you only intend to do this (takes **1.6 seconds**), or load the joined sequence in another `Seq` object:

```
seqs = []

with open("1Million.fas") as fasta:
    prev_seq = []
    for line in fasta:
        if line.startswith(">"):
            seqs.append("".join(prev_seq))
            prev_seq = []
        else:
            prev_seq.append(line.rstrip())

# This appends the lines after the last ">"
seqs.append("".join(prev_seq))

"NNNNNNNNNN".join(seqs)
```